# Git for windows seems to create sub-processes that never die

Tags: c#, process, git-for-windows

I use the following code to call `git` from C#:

```
var pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "git",
    Arguments = "checkout master",
    UseShellExecute = false
};

using var p = Process.Start(pInfo);
Console.WriteLine(p.Id);
p.WaitForExit();
```

The process ID printed is, lets say 3709. When my program ends, I look at the Task Manager and I see a `git.exe` process still running with a different ID, say 8865.  This process remains running indefinitely.

It seems to me that the `git` process started by my program spawns a second `git` process that never exits.  Is there any way for me to prevent this behavior?  As it is, every time I run my program, there is yet another `git.exe` process left behind indefinitely, adding up to a lot over time, until I reboot.

(Alternatively, is there any other way to invoke `git` other than by running the executable?)

Comment: I ended up "solving" this by programmatically killing all git.exe processes after each execution. Far from ideal

Answer (score 1):

You can disable spawning of those processes with:
`git config --global core.fsmonitor false`

You can also checkout [this issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4779).